# How to replace the characters in a string

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I have a method that I want to use to replace characters in a string:

```
def complexity_level_two
  replacements = {
      'i' => 'eye', 'e' => 'eei',
      'a' => 'aya', 'o' => 'oha'}
  word = "Cocoa!55"
  word_arr = word.split('')
  results = []
  word_arr.each { |char|
    if replacements[char] != nil
      results.push(char.to_s.gsub!(replacements[char]))
    else
      results.push(char)
    end
  }
end
```

My desired output for the string should be: `Cohacohaaya!55`

However when I run this method, it will not replace the characters and only outputs the string:

```
C
o
c
o
a
!
5
5
```

What am I doing wrong that makes this method not replace the correct characters inside of the string to match that in the `hash`? How can I fix this to get the desired output?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
replacements = {
  'i' => 'eye', 'e' => 'eei',
  'a' => 'aya', 'o' => 'oha'}
word = "Cocoa!55"
word.gsub(Regexp.union(replacements.keys), replacements)
#⇒ "Cohacohaaya!55"
```

[`Regexp::union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union), [`String#gsub` with hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub).

Comment: I'm slightly confused by that..?

Comment: Nice, I've never seen `gsub(pattern, hash)`. You should edit your comment about `gsub with block`, though.

Answer (score 1):

#### Constructing a method

Define your method with *word* and *subs* parameters:

```
def char_replacer word, subs
  word.chars.map { |c| subs.key?(c) ? subs[c] : c }.join
end
```

Here we've used the ternary operator which is essentially an if-else expression in a more compact form. Key methods to note are `String#chars`, `Array#map`, `Hash#key?`, see [ruby-docs](http://ruby-doc.org/) for more info on these. Now with this all set up, you can call your method passing a *word* string and the *subs* hash of your choosing.

#### Example 1

```
my_subs = { 'i' => 'eye', 'e' => 'eei','a' => 'aya', 'o' => 'oha' }
my_word = "Cocoa!55"

char_replacer my_word, my_subs #=> "Cohacohaaya!55"
```

#### Example 2

```
my_subs = { 'a' => 'p', 'e' => 'c' }
my_word = "Cocoa!55"

char_replacer my_word, my_subs #=> "Cocop!55"
```

Comment: Instead of ternary one might simply use `subs[c] || c`.

Comment: @mudasobwa ahh yes much better.

Answer (score 1):

```
replacements = { 'i' => 'eye', 'e' => 'eei', 'a' => 'aya', 'o' => 'oha' }.
  tap { |h| h.default_proc = ->(h,k) { k } }

"Cocoa!55".gsub(/./, replacements)
  #=> "Cohacohaaya!55"
```

See [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) and [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap).

`gsub` examines each character of the string. If `replacements` has that character as a key, the character is replaced with the value of that key in `replacements`; else (because of the default proc), the character is replaced with itself (that is, left unchanged).

Another way would be to use [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch):

```
replacements = { 'i' => 'eye', 'e' => 'eei', 'a' => 'aya', 'o' => 'oha' }

"Cocoa!55".gsub(/./) { |s| replacements.fetch(s) { |c| c } }
  #=> "Cohacohaaya!55"
```

which, for Ruby v2.2+ (when [Object#itself](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) made its debut), can be written

```
"Cocoa!55".gsub(/./) { |s| replacements.fetch(s, &:itself) }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to do this:

```
my_subs = { 'i' => 'eye', 'e' => 'eei','a' => 'aya', 'o' => 'oha' }
my_word = "Cocoa!55"
my_word.split('').map{|i| my_subs[i] || i}.join
```

=> "Cohacohaaya!55"