# How do I replace consecutive occurrences of white space in each element of my array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

Using Ruby 2.4. I have an array of strings. I want to strip off non-breaking and breaking space from the end of each item in the array as well as replace multiple consecutive occurrences of white space with a single white space. I thought teh below was the way, but I get an error

```
 > words = ["1", "HUMPHRIES \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t, \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tJASON", "328", "FAIRVIEW, OR (US)", "US", "M", " 27 ", "00:27:30.00 \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n"]

 > words.map{|word| word ? word.gsub!(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '').gsub!(/[[:space:]]+/, ' ') : nil }
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):4:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):4:in `map'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How can I properly replace consecutive occurrences of white space as well as strip it off from each word in the array?

Comment: Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306355/how-to-replace-the-characters-in-a-string

Comment: Thanks but this answer doesn't address how to remove non-breaking/breaking space from the ends of each word in the array.

Comment: @Natalia Can we tidy up your question a little? Remove the irb command prompts `2.4.0 :003` etc; put a `#` in front of outputs and correct your typos. Thanks.

Comment: there are alternatives to `gsub` - `tr`, `delete` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749065/what-is-the-difference-between-tr-and-gsub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with simple `gsub` not `gsub!`

```
words.map do |w|
  #respond_to?(:gsub) if you are not sure that array only from strings
  w.gsub(/(?<=[^\,\.])\s+|\A\s+/, '') if w.respond_to?(:gsub)
end
```

Because `gsub!` can return `nil` if don't change the string and then you try to do `gsub!` again with `nil`. That's why you get an `undefined method gsub!' for nil:NilClass` error.

From [gsub!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) explanation in ruby doc:

> Performs the substitutions of String#gsub in place, returning str, or
>   nil if no substitutions were performed. If no block and no replacement
>   is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

**As mentioned @CarySwoveland in comments `\s` doesn't handle non-breaking spaces. To handle it you should use `[[:space:]]` insted of `\s`.**

Comment: I don't understand your code. When it's run `self` is `main` and `main` doesn't have a method `gsub`. Also, it doesn't remove non-breaking spaces (e.g.,  [Unicode'a non-break space](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) `\00A0`), a requirement of the spec.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, it was a typo with `gsub` call after the last edit. Problem was not in the regex in this question, but you are right - `\s` doesn't match non-break space, but it's easy to handle with changing `\s` on `[[:space:]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
words.map { |w| w.gsub(/(?<=[^\,\.])\s+/,'') }
 #=> ["1", "HUMPHRIES, JASON", "328", "FAIRVIEW,
 #     OR(US)", "US", "M", " 27", "00:27:30.00"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume all whitespace and non-breaking spaces at the send of each string are to be removed and, of what's left, all substrings of whitespace characters and non-breaking spaces is to be replaced by one space. (Natalia, if that's not correct please let me know in a comment.)

```
words =
  ["1",
   "HUMPHRIES \t\t\t\, \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tJASON",
   " M\u00A0    \u00A0",
   "    27 ",
   "00:27:30.00 \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n"]

R = /
    [[:space:]]     # match a POSIX bracket expression for one character
    (?=[[:space:]]) # match a POSIX bracket expression for in a positive lookahead
    |               # or
    [[:space:]]+    # match a POSIX bracket expression one or more times
    \z              # match end of string
    /x              # free-spacing regex definition mode

words.map { |w| w.gsub(R, '').gsub(/[[:space:]]/, ' ') }
  #=> ["1", "HUMPHRIES , JASON", " M", " 27", "00:27:30.00"]
```

Note that the POSIX `[[:space:]]` includes ASCII whitespace and Unicode's non-breaking space character, `\u00A0`.

To see why the second `gsub` is needed, note that

```
words.map { |w| w.gsub(R, '') }
  #=> ["1", "HUMPHRIES\t,\tJASON", " M", " 27", "00:27:30.00"]
```